# Debugging Register Error

Tags: square-connect

So I'm seeing the "**API Error** Sorry, we could not process the incoming request. Please try again or contact support." message

I'm told that the app in question is authorized to use the Square Commerce API. I've made sure that I'm url-escaping my JSON.

This is what my json and link look like:

```
{"amount_money":
{"amount":100,"currency_code":"USD"},
"callback_url":"http://some_url/more_url/738",
"client_id":"secret_client_id",
"merchant_id":"secret_merchant_id",
"options":
{"supported_tender_types":["CREDIT_CARD"]}}


square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data=%7B%22amount_money%22:%7B%22amount%22:100,%22currency_code%22:%22USD%22%7D,%22callback_url%22:%22mah/url%22,%22client_id%22:%22secret%22,%22merchant_id%22:secret,%22options%22:%7B%22supported_tender_types%22:[%22CREDIT_CARD%22]%7D%7D
```

can anyone see anything I'm missing? Is there any way of getting more information out of the error message? Is there a list somewhere of the possible reasons?

Comment: I don't have my callback url set up on the app page, could that be related?

Comment: I set it up, it didn't help :(

Comment: I can confirm with a great deal of confidence that the client_id and merchant_id are correct.

Comment: received a response from square's dev team:

the currency type should be the same as the Square account settings.
Make sure a iOS App Bundle ID and OS App Callback URL are correctly set in their app settings
If they are using a web app, all these settings still need to be set
set any fake value for OS App Callback URL

Comment: I've ensured that these are all set correctly, and am still seeing an error and not receiving a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it ends up that Square sends this message for a variety of reasons, the big one here was that Square Register was set to 'Offline Mode'.

Disabling offline mode (in square register) resolves the error.